# Faster R-CNN: can changing LOSS_WEIGHTS make sense?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions

I'm working with a ton of images where measurements are made on a single class, it's way more important for me to have accurate bounding boxes than having slightly more detections. To me, this sounds like a case where it would make sense to increase the loss weight of mrcnn_bbox_loss. I however didn't find any resources explaining best practices of doing so.

I compared weights of 1, 3 and 5 for mrcnn_bbox_loss and the val_mrcnn_bbox_loss obviously also has those factors, so i divided each val_mrcnn_bbox_loss by its weight. The graphs were pretty identical after that. (Only 3 individual runs, still thinking about whether cross-validation would make sense) So is this something you do, because I saw people recommend it. And if yes, what am I doing wrong?